# Error 1934 : Drop failed for User 'username'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I keep getting this error everytime I try to delete a user from the database :

1. Expand the database
2. Expand Security
3. Expand Users
4. Right-click 'username' then select Delete

The following error occurs :

Drop failed for User 'username'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

**Additional Information:**

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

CONDITIONAL failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'.
Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or query notifications and/or xml data type methods. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1934)

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is supposed to be a fix, but it does work for the moment.
Just run this on the DB :

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
DROP USERNAME
SET ARITHABORT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Check sp_configure to see what "user options" is set to. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763.aspx

I came across some things that also pointed to an audit trigger that could throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC SP_configure 'user options', 8 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).